# How to add an image to a UIButton so that it isn't stretched to fill the button?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIButton, and I'm adding an image to it using this code:

```
[btnCall setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phoneicon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The problem is that this image is being stretched to fill the button, and I don't want it to be stretched at all - I want it to retain its "natural" size and be positioned in the center of the button, even when the button is resized.

My searching on this topic shows a bunch of people with the opposite problem: they're setting the image and they *want* it to be stretched to fill the button. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is because the default content mode is set to 'UIViewContentModeScaleToFill' so you need to set it to 'UIViewContentModeCenter'

```
btnCall.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: doesnt work for me...i have the same problem. what size should I set the UIbutton to?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me